# Something very funky is happening to my reputation score

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today my SO score topped 100k, peaked at around 100,050 and shortly afterwards dropped to 99,977.

What could be causing this? I investigated further, and noticed this:

If I go via https://stackoverflow.com/ my reputation on the top bar shows 99,977.

If I go via https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ it is 100,062.

I think that the higher total is correct, as (cue the drum roll) I passed the 100k mark on SO today.

I tracked through my reputation history and it shows a large spike on Jan 14th of this year, which I recall, wasn't there on the day itself.

Comment: How did you get to 100k without ever noticing this?

Comment: @Mysticial: Notice what? It's been steadily increasing. I wasn't aware of any "overstated" reputation being accumulated.

Comment: @Bathsheba Notice that MSO and SO don't always have their reputation 100% in sync.

Comment: Hum. I think I've offered the MSO as a red herring. I've edited the queastion to reflect that. What happened is that today my reputation on SO crept over the 100k mark, then all of a sudden it reduced to the total above. What would cause that?

Comment: So - are you asking about the difference between the MSO and SO rep, or asking about the drop in your SO rep?

Comment: The latter. Apologies. (It dropped suddenly and the MSO obviously retained the old total until manually resynchronised by @Servy).

Comment: Go to your reputation page - click the checkbox at the bottom (says "show removed posts"). This will show that a highly voted answer of yours got deleted (actually - the question was deleted, and all the answers on it), as was the reputation you got from it.

Comment: Congrats on the 6-figure rep score! Does SE still give out free swag to everyone who hits 100k? (If so, will they give you two sets for hitting it twice? :-P )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've manually synced your MSO profile with your SO profile.

As noted [by Servy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290637/140505) - the child-meta reputation is updated on a schedule so can drift for a short while.

---

Update:

Given that you are asking about the drop in your reputation and not the synchronizing issue - you can check what happened by going to the reputation tab of your profile and checking the "show removed posts" checkbox near the bottom of the page.

This will show that a highly voted post of yours got deleted, which is what caused your reputation to drop.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the story. I seldom visit MSO (in fact I only did when attempting to see what the problem could be). Looking at my reputation history, I also have a big spike on the 14 January of this year.

Comment: @Bathsheba - not sure why you think visiting MSO has anything to do with it. We sync reputation from SO to MSO on a schedule. If you lose reputation on SO, it won't be reflected in MSO for a while (it is also possible that a synchronisation failed - it wouldn't be retried until SO rep changed again).

Comment: That's the one! Thank you, and I get to experience the exhilaration of passing through 100k twice.

Answer (score 5):

Caching.  Always caching.

Child-Meta reputation doesn't update in real time.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the story. I seldom visit MSO (in fact I only did when attempting to see what the problem could be). Looking at my reputation history, I also have a big spike on the 14 January of this year.

Comment: @Bathsheba How does how often you visit MSO matter?  The amount that it was off is less than what you've earned in the past few hours; it's not like it was weeks out of date.